# Use of django-modeltranslation with django-filter

Tags: django, translation, django-filter

I'm constructing Django-based 4-language website for a real estate agency. I'm using django-modeltranslation for translation and django-filter package to filter property objects by certain parameters, such as type (house, apartment, etc.), city and some others.

The 'type' of a property is a foreign key of the related model 'Type'. It uses ModelChoiceFilter to select all available types from the database, and render them as a select element with options, which is and is displayed as a drop list with options, which is good so far.

class SalePropertyFilter(FilterSet):
...

```
type = ModelChoiceFilter(
    queryset=Type.objects.all(),
    empty_label=_("Any type"),
    label="",
    widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )
```

However, the drop-down list looks ugly, since the field label is not translated, and the options are displayed as slug names of the related model.

What I want is that options are displayed as common names of types (which are in the field 'name') instead of slug names, and they should be translated. That means, in the English version of the site options should be rendered from the field 'name_en', in the Spanish version - from 'name_es', etc.

There should be a proper way to do it. Please, help, I'm stuck!

[image: The dropdown list looks ugly: options are slug names (should be names) and not translated]